# convert svg from web to png

Tags: python, svg

I'm using python and trying to read an svg file from the web and convert it to png.
Here is an example url for the svg file:

```
example_url = 'http://cdn.nba.net/assets/logos/teams/secondary/web/PHI.svg'
```

A few years ago I was able to read the svg and convert it to string using:

```
s = cairosvg.svg2png(url=example_url)
```

But now it is trying to concatenate my example_url to my local path and I get an error.

My final goal is to plot it with matplotlib.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: error? please include in the question the full text of the error you got

Comment: It says "[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" because it is concatenating my example_url to my local path

Comment: `example_url` needs to be the image file, not a string url

Answer (score 1):

`example_url` needs to be the image file, not a string url. Try this:

```
import urllib

example_url = 'http://cdn.nba.net/assets/logos/teams/secondary/web/PHI.svg'

img = urllib.request.urlretrieve(example_url, "PHI.svg")

s = cairosvg.svg2png(url=img)
```